# How to Count Multiple Colomuns and Fields in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to count multiple columns and fields using a single query with mysql and php.

Basically, i want to count how many clicks, conversions and clicks through a keyword has got like the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag2At.png

This is my db structure:

```
click id -> click_id<br>
keyword -> kw<br>
clicks through -> click_th<br>
conversions -> conv<br>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Wag.png

So that'd be:

- The keyword 'test' received 2 clicks, 1 went through and 0 conversion.
- The keyword 'test2' received 2 clicks, 2 went through and 2 conversions.

I figured out how to count how many clicks a keyword got using this:

```
$query = "SELECT kw, COUNT(click_id)  FROM clicks GROUP BY kw ORDER by COUNT(click_id) DESC ";
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to **sum** the click through and conversion amounts.  Luckily, mysql has a SUM function.

```sql
SELECT kw, COUNT(click_id), SUM(click_th), SUM(conv)
FROM clicks
GROUP BY kw ORDER BY COUNT(click_id) DESC
```